# How can I hide all videos from a given channel on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

How can I hide all videos from a given channel on YouTube? By hiding I mean never recommending any video from the given channel.

Comment: If you are logged in and the channel shows up on your homepage, there's an "X" along the "Subscribe" button that means "I'm not interested". Have you tried clicking on it to see if it works?

Comment: I tried but I don't think it hides all the videos from the channel. Does it?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried (because I browse Youtube without logging in). If you do that, does it still show you videos from that channel?

Comment: I believe clicking on hide makes it less likely to get recommended videos, but I would guess it just reduces the probability instead of setting it to 0 and it is possible that the similarity is defined differently from belonging to the same channel. But I'll try using this feature a bit more and will let you know if it does trick.

Comment: When you logged in and see recommendations, and hover the mouse over a video you don't want, there appears three dots on the right.  Click on the dots, and one of the options is “Don’t recommend channel”. Isn't it just what you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extensions like Video Blocker ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/video-blocker/)) that allow this - but nothing you can do with native YouTube tools.